# Best way to handle missing file in azureml Dataset from_delimited_files call

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have the following code statement in Python with the AzureML SDK, that works great, unless if there are no files matching the partition name wildcard filter.

In that case, an exception is thrown.  (see error below the code).  I can obviously catch the Error and check for the description, but I would prefer to have a way to check if there's a file matching the given file name.  What would be the best way (without impacting performance too much) here?

**The code**:

```py
partition_name = 'BE*'
datastore_name = 'ml'

from azureml.core import Workspace, Dataset, Datastore
from azureml.data.datapath import DataPath

ws = Workspace.from_config()
datastore = Datastore(ws, name=datastore_name)
dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(header=False,
                    path=DataPath(datastore, '/' + partition_name + '.csv')) 
df = aml_dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
```

**The exception:**

```
ExecutionError: The provided path is not valid or the files could not be accessed.
(No files were found using path provided. Please make sure the path you've specified is correct, 
files exist and can be accessed.)|session_id=xxx 
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

DatasetValidationError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
```

Comment: you want to check if there's files that match the wildcard BEFORE you try and create the dataset?

Comment: Hey @AndersSwanson, thx for commenting.  That's what I want, or just indicate (passing a flag?) that it's okay if there's no file matching that pattern.  Everything better than the try except cause, as far as I see it

Comment: @SamVanhoutte you can pass a flag `validate=False` and `infer_column_types=False` to [from_delimited_files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.data.dataset_factory.tabulardatasetfactory?view=azure-ml-py#from-delimited-files-path--validate-true--include-path-false--infer-column-types-true--set-column-types-none--separator------header-true--partition-format-none--support-multi-line-false--empty-as-string-false-)  to indicate it's ok if there is no file matching that pattern.

Comment: @MayHu , even when using these args , I get the exception as soon as I execute the .to_pandas_dataframe method.  I don't seem to have a way of checking if the dataset contains data or not?

Comment: there is no specific method to check whether there is matching file.

Comment: okay, that's what I thought.  sticking to the exception handling part, then :(